# FloatingActionButton ignores animations (KitKat)

Tags: android, animation, android-4.4-kitkat, floating-action-button

I declare a `FloatingActionButton` in my xml layout

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/random_button_margin"
        android:onClick = "randomButtonPressed"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_dice"
        android:id="@+id/randomButton"/>
```

and some animations in xml, such as `fade_out.xml` and `rotate.xml`.

```
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:duration="1000"/>

</set>
```

and

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <rotate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="359"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1000" />

</set>
```

Calling either of these animations on an arbitrary view, such as a `TextSwitcher`, successfully fades out or rotates the view. Calling the identical functions but on my `FloatingActionButton` fails; there is no visible response of the button whatsoever.

```
findViewById(R.id.mTextView).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate))
```

I'm compiling the app to my phone (A Samsung S4 with Android 4.4.2).

Why does my button seem to be un-animatable?

Comment: I think you have to use the newer [Property Animations](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) with a `FloatingActionButton`, instead of the old View Animations. That is, the classes in the `android.animation` package, rather than `android.view.animation`.

Comment: @MikeM. That also didn't work. `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(findViewById(R.id.randomButton), "rotation", 0f, 359f)`

Comment: Works for me. Did you `start()` the animator?

Comment: @MikeM. Kicking myself. You've solved it (you should write an answer)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hesitant to do so until I can confirm that the old View Animations just don't work with a FloatingActionButton. I'm gonna do a little research first.

Comment: Some food for thought then. This works (but once, and thereafter introduces a strange shadow clipping): `ViewCompat.animate(findViewById(R.id.randomButton)).rotation(359).withLayer().setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator()).start();`